# $q.all не ждет пока все промисы не решаться

Tags: angularjs, promise

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('ctrl', ['$scope', '$timeout', '$q',
  function($scope, $timeout, $q) {
    var results = [{
      id: 1,
      name: 'one'
    }, {
      id: 2,
      name: 'two'
    }, {
      id: 3,
      name: 'three'
    }];
    var promisesFunction = function() {
      var uploadPromises = [],
        printforms = [],
        printPromises = [],
        printDefer = [],
        counter = 0,
        defer = $q.defer();


      angular.forEach(results, function(temp, key) {
        // first delay
        $timeout(function() {
          var html = '<div><span>My Name Is Jack</span></div>';
          var data = {
            sFunnyName: 'fluffy.html',
            sContent: '<p>some content</p>'
          };

          printDefer[key] = $q.defer();
          printforms[key] = {
            html: html,
            data: data
          };
          printPromises[key] = printDefer[key].promise;
          defer.resolve();
        });
        uploadPromises.push(defer.promise);
      });

      var asyncUpload = function(i, print, defs) {
        if (i < print.length) {
          // emulation of $http.post
          console.log('Start upload ' + i);
          $timeout(function() {
            results[i].value = 'done';
            printDefer[i].resolve();
            console.log(results[i].value + ' ' + i);
            ++i;
            asyncUpload(i, print, defs);
          }, 1000);
        }
      };

      // this $q.all wait until first delay is done for all 3 elemets. 
      // Then upload this items.
      var first = $q.all(uploadPromises).then(function() {
        console.log('First promise is done!');
        asyncUpload(counter, printforms, printDefer);
      });

      // this $q.all wait until all items is loaded.
      $q.all([first, printPromises]).then(function(uploadResults) {
        console.log('RESOLVED!')
      });

    }
    promisesFunction();

  }
])
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Example</title>
</head>

<body ng-controller='ctrl'>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

У меня массив объектов. Я хочу загрузить их все и потом вернуть все результаты вместе, одним скопом. Но в моей функции есть 2 задержки, в связи с этим решил использовать промисы:

1. `$timeout` (он нужен чтобы подождать пока `$compile` скомпилирует контент с моих обьектов, но в этом не суть), 2
2. `$http.post` (когда я уже скомпилированный контент с объектами передаю на сервер).

Поэтому я использую `$q.all` чтобы дождаться когда все эти действия будут проведены. В деббагере я вижу, что некоторые промисы с статусом еще 0, но уже `$q.all` их пропустил. Подскажите, где я ошибся?

[Пример jsbin который полностью симулирует ситуацию.](https://jsbin.com/yewusopihu/3/edit?js,console)

Comment: Код должен быть непосредственно в вопросе, кроме того, в вопрос можно вставить [_сниппет_](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/4619/186999) демонстрирующий проблему

Comment: сейчас попробую вставить что нужно) просто в jsbin консоль где видно выполнение..

Comment: Во встроенных сниппетах она так же показывается по умолчанию

Comment: и да, я уже вижу неверное использование :-) так что добавляй

Comment: @Grundy получилось!) обновил)

Comment: отдельно делать переменную с `$q.al`l для `printPromises` нет смысла, тк еще этих промиссов нет до резолва `first`.. я думал что по идее после резолва `first`, должен проверится решен ли массив с `printPromises`.. но, к сожалению, он с статусом 0 его пропускает

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52356/discussion-between-grundy-and-yorodiallo).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема заключается в *потере* обещаний.

Если внутри `then` создается новое обещание, но не возвращается, то оно теряется и его никак нельзя отследить.

В предоставленном коде несколько мест с потерянными обещаниями:

1. В первом цикле, теряется обещание от $timeout

   ```
   angular.forEach(results, function(temp, key) {
       // first delay
       $timeout(function() {...})
   ```

   1. внутри обработчика $timeout переводится в resolve глобальный defer, то есть он сработает один раз для первого $timeout, и по сути в *uploadPromises* лежат несколько ссылок на один и тот же объект.
2. тот же самый утекший $timeout в функции *asyncUpload*.

Решение: возвращать все promise

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('ctrl', ['$scope', '$timeout', '$q',
  function($scope, $timeout, $q) {
    var results = [{
      id: 1,
      name: 'one'
    }, {
      id: 2,
      name: 'two'
    }, {
      id: 3,
      name: 'three'
    }];
    var promisesFunction = function() {
      var uploadPromises = [],
        printforms = [],
        printPromises = [],
        printDefer = [],
        counter = 0;

      angular.forEach(results, function(temp, key) {
        // first delay
        uploadPromises.push($timeout(function() {
          var html = '<div><span>My Name Is Jack</span></div>';
          var data = {
            sFunnyName: 'fluffy.html',
            sContent: '<p>some content</p>'
          };

          printDefer[key] = $q.defer();
          printforms[key] = {
            html: html,
            data: data
          };
          printPromises[key] = printDefer[key].promise;
        }));
      });

      var asyncUpload = function(i, print, defs) {
        if (i < print.length) {
          // emulation of $http.post
          console.log('Start upload ' + i);
          return $timeout(function() {
            results[i].value = 'done';
            printDefer[i].resolve();
            console.log(results[i].value + ' ' + i);
            return asyncUpload(i + 1, print, defs);
          }, 1000);
        }
      };

      // this $q.all wait until first delay is done for all 3 elemets. 
      // Then upload this items.
      var first = $q.all(uploadPromises).then(function() {
        console.log('First promise is done!');
        return asyncUpload(counter, printforms, printDefer);
      });

      // this $q.all wait until all items is loaded.
      $q.all([first, printPromises]).then(function(uploadResults) {
        console.log('RESOLVED!')
      });

    }
    promisesFunction();

  }
])
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Example</title>
</head>

<body ng-controller='ctrl'>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, действительно помогло, еще немного переварю код чтобы вникнуть окончательно) зы. спасибо за подсказку о снипетах, раньше не пользовался, теперь буду!

Comment: подскажи, плз, все таки почему $q.all пропускает если в массиве есть элемент с $$status 0. по идее же только с статусом 1 должен пропускать?

Comment: @YoroDiallo, что ты имеешь ввиду говоря _пропускает_ и элемент с `$$status 0`? Обработчик `then` у обещания которое возвратит `$q.all` выполнится когда **все** обещания в переданном массиве будут в статусе resolved. Непонятно где ты можешь видеть _$$status 0_. И как ты вообще проверяешь.

Comment: твое обьяснение я понял, сделал правки в "боевом" коде, и все сработало до 2го запроса на `$http.post` выполнения которого не дождалось и выполнило 2й `$q.all`. это где-то мой бок, конечно же, я пытаюсь его выявить) проследил в дебаггере, в обьекте с промиссами, на 1й (`first`) статус 1, на 2й массив (`printPromises`) на 1м элементе статус 1, на вотором 0, но `then` срабатывает

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> var ...
>      defer = $q.defer();
>
> angular.forEach(results, function(temp, key) {
>     $timeout(function() {
>         ...
>         defer.resolve();
>     });
>     uploadPromises.push(defer.promise);
> ```

Один и тот же `defer` принадлежит всем элементам массива. Соответственно, первый из них ресолвит все промисы (точнее, единственный промис, который многократно помещён в массив).

Исправляется так:

```
angular.forEach(results, function(temp, key) {
    var defer = $q.defer();

    $timeout(function() {
        ...
        defer.resolve();
    });

    uploadPromises.push(defer.promise);
```

Кстати, помещение промиса в массив вполне можно поднять наверх:

```
angular.forEach(results, function(temp, key) {
    var defer = $q.defer();
    uploadPromises.push(defer.promise);

    $timeout(function() {
        ...
        defer.resolve();
    });
```

либо вообще использовать `map` и другой синтаксис:

```
uploadPromises = results.map(function(temp, key) {
  return $q(function (resolve, reject) {
    ...
    resolve();
  });
});
```

или даже так:

```
uploadPromises = results.map(function(temp, key) {
  return $timeout(function() { // Ну или $http.get
    ...
  });
});
```

Comment: вроде не один `defer`, для `uploadPromises` это defer(`defer = $q.defer()`), а для printPromises это `printDefer (`printDefer[key] = $q.defer()`), или я не так понял?

Comment: Там лучше сразу в массив результаты $timeout складывать, без ручных defer

Comment: @Grundy, да, забыл, что там промис. Но это же всё равно для примера было. Дополнил.

Comment: Спасибо большое всем за помощь, вроде все понятно, но еще немножко посижу с вашим кодом чтобы вникнуть глубже, немножко запутался)